# Pulse Area Uncertainty for a given Sample Rate and Bit Resolution

Tags: optics, measurements, electronics, measurement-problem, signal-processing

I'm recording pulses and want to approximately know how precise I can measure this with my Oscilloscope. I'm recording with 15 bit vertical resolution -> 1/(2^15) and a sample rate of 125 MS/s -> 8 ns sampling period.
Am I correct in assuming that lets say the Area is approximately a Square and thus I have a precision on length of 16 ns (t2-t1) and a precision on height of V_range/(2^15)? This would give a precision on the area of 1.6*10^-3.

Comment: What do your pulses represent? What duration? Generally, what you propose, directly sampling pulses and attempting to integrate the result, does not work very well.

Comment: The two important values for a resolution of an oscilloscope are its bandwidth (how fast it can respond to transients) and then your sample frequency, which will, through the nyquist-shannon theorem tell you the highest effective frequency that you can measure. What you wrote here is not, per se, indicative of its appropriateness for whatever you want to measure. After making a proper measurement, then you can calculate your precision.